# How can I set up an ActiveAdmin editor for a singleton model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

The active admin page should load the singleton instance of the model (I am using an ActiveRecord compliant model). I'm not sure where to put the code to load the single instance of the model, or how to make the default page for the record be an edit page rather than the collection page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#member_actions, and, you can set the actions to:

```
actions :update
```

In the member action you can focus to update the instance.

--

Hi again, today I did something like that, simpler, and this is what I did:

1. Make the index look like a blog http://activeadmin.info/docs/3-index-pages/index-as-blog.html
2. Only use actions: index, edit, update
3. Use a scope http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#scoping_the_queries (also, you can use only **scope** and not **scope_to** if you want to call a scope from the model).

Hope it helps.